# What is LeakCanary complaining about in this leak trace?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

```
====================================
HEAP ANALYSIS RESULT
====================================
1 APPLICATION LEAKS
 
References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.
 
1349 bytes retained by leaking objects
Signature: fbba65ae31efd4f2c9cce2a7189127798c896c7f
┬───
│ GC Root: Global variable in native code
│
├─ android.telecom.InCallService$InCallServiceBinder instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 1.9 kB in 12 objects
│    this$0 instance of com.redacted.company.CallService
│    instance InCallService$InCallServiceBinder@317901080
│    ↓ InCallService$InCallServiceBinder.this$0
│                                        ~~~~~~
╰→ com.redacted.company.CallService instance
     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.redacted.company.CallService received Service#onDestroy() callback and Service not held by ActivityThread)
     Retaining 1.3 kB in 11 objects
     key = 4658065d-2277-46cb-ad96-3de0440b039b
     watchDurationMillis = -3481823
     retainedDurationMillis = -3486830
     mApplication instance of com.redacted.company.MyApplication
     mBase instance of android.app.ContextImpl
     instance CallService@321294080
====================================
0 LIBRARY LEAKS
 
A Library Leak is a leak caused by a known bug in 3rd party code that you do not have control over.
See https://square.github.io/leakcanary/fundamentals-how-leakcanary-works/#4-categorizing-leaks
====================================
0 UNREACHABLE OBJECTS
 
An unreachable object is still in memory but LeakCanary could not find a strong reference path
from GC roots.
====================================
```

Is it complaining about a leak in android.telecom.InCallService$InCallServiceBinder?

I've reduced the code in my CallService class to simple super.() only calls for the onCallAdded and onCallRemoved functions, so my leak can't be in there.

Comment: I have had this problem as well, did you get any solution?

Comment: It looks like the leak happens because InCallServiceBinder holds a reference to its outer class, InCallService.

Answer (score 0):

(Edits: 3 (Solved))

## TLDR.:

After a configuration change, a new Service instance will be recreated (this may depend on the flag type of the Intent that helped spawn the Service... I am not sure about this... but for this specific leak to occur... the behavior must follow an instance recreation of the Service....
Assuming a specific flag configuration allows to spawn a single Service that becomes application-bound (instead of Activity-bound) that would prevent a Service recreation upon configuration change... then, that would also be deemed a possible solution.)

A leak will occur when a Service of a previous Activity's instance is recaptured ("held") by the new instance, either it be a new Activity or Fragment instance, or whatever new instanced that is bound to a new recreated `Context`.

- Possible cause:

The Service `onDestroy()` phase gets called extremely late during configuration change, **making it possible to grab a Service associated with a previous caller**, in this case a `MainActivity` during the `onCreate()` phase of a new MainActivity instance, or even during the `onStart()` phase of a deeply nested Fragment of this new MainActivity instance.

## Original:

I think I found why I had this issue.

My Fragment was in a state where it retained its inner state on config change. (cannot remember what was the name of this state)...

I am grabbing a Service instance from the main Activity.

If my hunch is correct, then the issue should resolve by nulling the Service instance during either "onStop"... or "onPause"... why not onDestroy()???

because this configuration that retains state... does NOT seem to be forcing an onDestroy() during config change...

This means that an old Service instance bound to a previous Activity instance... is kept inside the Fragment's "carcass"... inside the stack of reusable Fragments.... which is still weird... if my mind is correct... an Activity will never have a shorter lifespan than that of a Fragment... no matter which configuration...

I'll update if this works...

## Edit 1:

It worked... but there are still issues...

Ok... there are a lot of things...

The main issue with this "leak" seems to be that it may actually be a false positive... **but done in very good faith**...

The reason why this is left as a possible leak is because the Service... calls "onDestroy()" extremely late in the Activity recreation process.

As far as I understand... the Android architecture calls a Singleton for each Service called during application lifetime... YET

(There is a contradiction here)

during configuration change... because the Service is destroyed very late in the process... there are 2 Activities simultaneously...

(The contradiction is that if the application's priority is to have a singleton, why is the lifespan of this singleton tied to that of it's caller instead of Application??)

So... the Activity itself that calls for a "bind" process... IGNORES the previous state.... then every Fragment that gets re-activated from the backstack/background... reacquires this new instance associated with the new activity.

If the user takes care of Service instances statically for optimization reasons...
(This is not difficult since the Service has "agency"... because of its inner lifecycle callbacks: onCreate()... onDestroy())
... the Activity instance could be retaken from the old Service while it still has not being destroyed.

This is why LeakCanary is so preoccupied to leave the Service's onDestroy() inside "ActivityThread"...

Now my main question is... WHY?

If a singleton is a main priority for all children (of Activities...?) why not leave it as an application bound singleton??

Is this even possible?

My guess... If any user custom made reference of Service is still alive while Activity calls onDestroy... the leak will appear... which means... the Service's "onDestroy()" phase cannot be used to clear whatever reference is used for ease of reference retrieval.

This is my current leak message:

```
LeakCanary               D  1 APPLICATION LEAKS
LeakCanary               D  
LeakCanary               D  References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
LeakCanary               D  Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.
LeakCanary               D  
LeakCanary               D  9228 bytes retained by leaking objects
LeakCanary               D  Signature: 7ca3c30515336172bfd0943ba3a79c39266a1261
LeakCanary               D  ┬───
LeakCanary               D  │ GC Root: System class
LeakCanary               D  │
LeakCanary               D  ├─ android.provider.FontsContract class
LeakCanary               D  │    Leaking: NO (SomeApplication↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
LeakCanary               D  │    ↓ static FontsContract.sContext
LeakCanary               D  ├─ com.project.SomeApplication instance
LeakCanary               D  │    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking and Application is a singleton)
LeakCanary               D  │    mBase instance of android.app.ContextImpl
LeakCanary               D  │    ↓ BaseApplication.activities
LeakCanary               D  ├─ java.util.LinkedList instance
LeakCanary               D  │    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking)
LeakCanary               D  │    ↓ LinkedList[0]
LeakCanary               D  ├─ com.project.MainActivity instance
LeakCanary               D  │    Leaking: NO (AFragment2↓ is not leaking and Activity#mDestroyed is false)
LeakCanary               D  │    mApplication instance of com.project.SomeApplication
LeakCanary               D  │    mBase instance of android.app.ContextImpl
LeakCanary               D  │    ↓ ComponentActivity.mOnBackPressedDispatcher
LeakCanary               D  ├─ androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher instance
LeakCanary               D  │    Leaking: NO (EntryEditorPagerFragment2↓ is not leaking)
LeakCanary               D  │    ↓ OnBackPressedDispatcher.mOnBackPressedCallbacks
LeakCanary               D  ├─ java.util.ArrayDeque instance
LeakCanary               D  │    Leaking: NO (EntryEditorPagerFragment2↓ is not leaking)
LeakCanary               D  │    ↓ ArrayDeque.elements
LeakCanary               D  ├─ java.lang.Object[] array
LeakCanary               D  │    Leaking: NO (EntryEditorPagerFragment2↓ is not leaking)
LeakCanary               D  │    ↓ Object[9]
LeakCanary               D  ├─ com.project.AbstractFragment$2 instance
LeakCanary               D  │    Leaking: NO (EntryEditorPagerFragment2↓ is not leaking)
LeakCanary               D  │    Anonymous subclass of androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback
LeakCanary               D  │    ↓ AbstractFragment$2.this$0
LeakCanary               D  ├─ com.project.AFragment instance
LeakCanary               D  │    Leaking: NO (Fragment.mLifecycleRegistry.state is RESUMED)
LeakCanary               D  │    service instance of com.project.AService
LeakCanary               D  │    ↓ AFragment.service
LeakCanary               D  │                                ~~~~~~~
LeakCanary               D  ╰→ com.project.AService instance
LeakCanary               D  ​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.project.
LeakCanary               D  ​     AService received Service#onDestroy() callback and Service not held by ActivityThread)
LeakCanary               D  ​     Retaining 9.2 kB in 228 objects
LeakCanary               D  ​     key = edf792b0-fd0a-4a1c-923a-9c0103f1768e
LeakCanary               D  ​     watchDurationMillis = 1320089
LeakCanary               D  ​     retainedDurationMillis = 1315086
LeakCanary               D  ​     mApplication instance of com.project.SomeApplication
LeakCanary               D  ​     mBase instance of android.app.ContextImpl
```

As you can see... nothing is holding a strong reference... then all of a sudden... the very last reference is leaking...

I'll post if I manage to definitely solve the issue.

## Edit 2:

This may be extremely particular to my case... but I'm wondering if privately owned architectures may have the same issue.

So, it seems the Service's onDestroy() callback, comes so late during config change... that a Fragment's onStart() is able to pick on the previous instance... even before the new Service has finished recreating... this is in all honesty... awful.

This means that all of the Service-caller's children that want to acquire the Service instance... must connect a lambda function that reacts to the time in which the Service caller is ready to deliver the created Service's instance and this time may vary depending on whether it is a fresh new start... or a configuration change...

I'll post if this solves the issue...

## Edit 3: (For custom architectures)

Even though it seems as if the Service class is the one being "singled-out" via singleton pattern... the real singleton is NOT that of its Service class... but instead the one from its **Binder**.

So, the REAL singleton container... for those designs that aim to catch the singleton directly... is to acquire the Service via Binder reference.

The Binder is the one that is actually capable of inferring the "swap" from previous Service instance... to new Service instance.

But IMO it should not be delivered as an atomic OR synchronized... "just in time" swap.

The previous Service instance should have been collected/nulled **WAY before the Activity has called "onCreate()"** during a configuration change... something the Android architecture does not do??? (This may be because of the 'flag' used for Service initialization... idk, but anyways...)

If you want to cache the Service in some sort of static referencing mehcanism... like a Map of singletons, do it with its binder instead, and retrieve the Service through this reusable Binder... a Binder which must handle the setting and cleanup of "new" and "previous" Service instances.

Then, the "dispatch" operation for any Consumer waiting from any of the Frragments/or Activity children... that should retrieve the new version of the Service... listeners which should handle their own lifecycles ofc.